# Paypal refund API call

Tags: php, post, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I tried to make a post request to refund API with below mentioned code :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
          http_build_query(array('USER' => 'user','PWD' => '14235', 'SIGNATURE' => '14785' ,'METHODE' => RefundTransaction , VERSION => 94, TRANSACTIONID => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',REFUNDTYPE => Full)));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { } else {  }

echo $server_output;

?>
```

But it says

Server Connection Closed

Description: The server requested closed the connection before the transaction was completed.